# Julia lang: How to get Versioninformation of Windows processes?

Tags: windows, process, julia, fileversioninfo

How do I get the versioninformation of all running processes on a Windows Server in Julia?

Like "get-process -filversioninfo" in PowerShell?

I need all processes starting with "d" in a separate text file
(again powershell: get-process d* -fileversioninfo   >.\output.txt."

Thank you
Micha

Answer (score 0):

There might be some native dll calls wrappers in julia, but in this case I would just use run and pipelines to get what you want.

I got a bunch of red text and a thrown error from run when I initially did:

```
run(pipeline(`powershell -c 'get-process d* -fileversioninfo'`, stdout="output.txt"))
```

So I suppressed the errors and now I get this:

```
julia> run(pipeline(Cmd(`powershell -c 'get-process d* -fileversioninfo -ErrorAction Ignore'`, ignorestatus=true), stdout="output.txt"))
Process(`powershell -c 'get-process d* -fileversioninfo -ErrorAction Ignore'`, ProcessExited(1))

julia> println(read("output.txt", String))

ProductVersion   FileVersion      FileName
--------------   -----------      --------
10.0.22621.1     10.0.22621.1 ... C:\Windows\System32\DataExchangeHost.exe
10.0.22621.1     10.0.22621.1 ... C:\WINDOWS\system32\DllHost.exe
10.0.22621.1     10.0.22621.1 ... C:\WINDOWS\system32\DllHost.exe
10.0.22621.1     10.0.22621.1 ... C:\WINDOWS\system32\DllHost.exe
10.0.22621.1     10.0.22621.1 ... C:\WINDOWS\system32\DllHost.exe
10.0.22621.1     10.0.22621.1 ... C:\WINDOWS\system32\DllHost.exe
10.0.22621.1     10.0.22621.1 ... C:\WINDOWS\system32\DllHost.exe
```

Tested on Windows 11 with Julia 1.9.2.

See the documentation on `run` and `pipeline` and `Cmd` here:

https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/running-external-programs/

I like this function, too, but it does need to change `AbstractCmd` to support a pipeline inside.

https://discourse.julialang.org/t/collecting-all-output-from-shell-commands/15592/7

```
function communicate(cmd::Base.AbstractCmd, input="") # minor changes to args
    inp = Pipe()
    out = Pipe()
    err = Pipe()

    process = run(pipeline(cmd, stdin=inp, stdout=out, stderr=err), wait=false)
    close(out.in)
    close(err.in)

    stdout = @async String(read(out))
    stderr = @async String(read(err))
    write(process, input)
    close(inp)
    wait(process)
    # look at all exitcodes
    if process isa Base.ProcessChain
        exitcode = maximum([p.exitcode for p in process.processes])
    else
        exitcode = process.exitcode
    end

    return (
        stdout = fetch(stdout),
        stderr = fetch(stderr),
        code = process.exitcode
    )
end

@show communicate(`cat`, "hello")
@show communicate(`sh -c "cat; echo errrr 1>&2; exit 3"`, "hello")
```